# Fuzziness behavior on a match_phrase query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Days ago I got this "problem". I was running a `match_phrase` query in my index. Everything was as expected, until I did the same search with a multiple words nouns (before I was using single word nouns, eg: university). I made one misspelling and the search did not work (not found), if I removed a word (let's say the one that was spelled correctly), the search work (found).

Here there are the example I made:

**The settings**

```
PUT index1
{
  "mappings": {
    "myType": {
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST index1/myType/1
{
  "field1": "Commercial Banks"
}
```

**Case 1:** Single noun search

```
GET index1/myType/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "field1": {
        "type": "phrase", 
        "query": "comersial",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "took": 16,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.19178303,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index1",
        "_type": "myType",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.19178303,
        "_source": {
          "field1": "Commercial Banks"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Case 2:** Multiple noun search

```
GET index1/myType/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "field1": {
        "type": "phrase", 
        "query": "comersial banks",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

So, in the second case, why am I not finding the document when performing the `match_phrase` query? Is there something I am missing?
Those result just make doubt about what I know.
Am I using the fuzzy search incorrectly? I'm not sure if this is a problem, or I'm the one who do not understand the behavior.

Many thanks in advance for reading my question. I hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fuzziness is not supported in phrase queries.

Currently, ES is silent about it, i.e. it allows you to specify the parameter but doesn't warn you that it is not supported. A [pull request (#18322)](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/18322) (related to [issue #7764](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7764)) exists that will remedy to this problem. Once merged into ES 5, this query will error out.

In the [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/breaking_50_search_changes.html#_changes_to_queries) document for 5.0, we can see that this won't be supported:

> The `multi_match` query will fail if `fuzziness` is used for `cross_fields`, `phrase` or `phrase_prefix` type. This parameter was undocumented and silently ignored before for these types of `multi_match`.